Confusion about opposites and notation in Category Theory
I'm sure I am not the first one to struggle with this, so let us insist in helping this issue out of the world once and for all!
One comes across the sentence "$(-)^\mathrm{op}$ is functorial", absent further clarification. One might, a prima facie, well comfort oneself quickly by noting that "surely, $(-)^\mathrm{op}(F)$ is $F^\mathrm{op}$, whether it is viewed as $\left((-)^\mathrm{op}\right)_1(F)$ or as $\left((-)^\mathrm{op}\right)_0(F)$, right?
Right..? Or could it be that the implicit but definite and necessary choice we have made, namely to have $F$ come as equipped just with some categories $\mathcal{C} := \mathrm{dom}(F), \mathcal{D} := \mathrm{cod}(F)$ and some assignment $F(f)$ for any morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, or, in the second case, equipped, additionally, with natural transformations $µ : F \Rightarrow G$  that will have to then be mapped to some $µ^\mathrm{op}$ again, cause trouble in the future??
(To add clarity: I mean that $(-)^\mathrm{op}$ is (at least) bivalent: it might be a functor  →  or, a functor Cat → Cat, or even [, ] → [, ], by Jove, in the theory of presheaf categories, even $(-)^\mathrm{op} : [F, G] \to [G, F]$ could be confusing..! I fear to merely have subtracted clarity...)
Perhaps I'm splitting split hairs at this point, but I fear that someone will have to say something meaningful here, and I cannot, by nature, let it go until I am sure...

It's not clear what you're asking exactly. What type of object are you referring to exactly when you write "$(-)^{\operatorname{op}}$"?

See nLab for some of the subtleties related to the oppositisation functor. I also have no idea what you're asking.

@Smiley1000 That the entire reason of being for this post! IS there an canonical, preferred interpretation? If so, which? If not, when should we be careful, if at all?

The notation $(-)^\mathrm{op}$ is overloaded, which means that its meaning depends on the type of its operand. Once that is determined, there usually isn't any ambiguity. This isn't specific to $(-)^\mathrm{op}$, by the way; many notations in mathematics are overloaded. In fact all functors $F$ are typically overloaded, writing $F(X)$ for the action on objects and $F(f)$ for the action on morphisms.

@NaïmFavier, thank you, that is a great page! And thanks for the serious response. I'm sure I'm not the only one pulling their hairs wondering "I thought mathematics was designed to avoid ambiguity??", but it seems to come up with any language humans either design or develop... :/

Indeed, because humans aren't computers. We do come up with more or less unambiguous languages for talking to computers though. You might be interested in the formalisation of category theory in a dependently typed language; see here for example.

@NaïmFavier: I am in disagreement with the down votes and close votes on this post. In fact your comments would make an excellent answer.

In "informal" mathematical practice, we routinely overload notation to mean different things based on the types of its arguments. For example, $- + -$ can mean both addition of natural numbers and addition of real numbers (and many other things). This isn't a problem because we usually know the type of the things we're talking about.
In category theory, we typically overload every functor $F$ to stand for its own action on objects (as in $F(X)$) and its action on morphisms (as in $F(f)$). $(-)^\mathrm{op}$, the oppositisation (bi)functor on the (bi)category of categories, is no exception, and can also stand for its own action on 2-morphisms, i.e. natural transformations.
